Selenium session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error when running via cron in GUI mode
I'm trying to run a Selenium script using Google Chrome without headless mode in a cron job. When I execute the script manually under my user account, everything works fine. However, when I run the same script via cron (either from user or root), I get the following error:
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Things I've tried:

Running the script manually as a user: works perfectly.
Configuring crontab for both root and my user account, same error in both cases.
I've ensured the script is using the options object instead of chrome_options (since it's deprecated).

I need Chrome to run in GUI mode (not headless), but I can't get the cron job to do this without crashing. The error occurs only when the script is triggered via cron.
45 9 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/project/script.py >> /home/user/cron_log.txt 2>&1


I believe the issue arises because cron jobs run in a non-GUI environment, which prevents Chrome from starting properly in non-headless mode.
To resolve this, you can use Xvfb to provide a virtual display:

Install Xvfb: (For Debian based)
sudo apt-get install xvfb


Update Your Cron Job to Use Xvfb:
45 9 * * * /usr/bin/xvfb-run /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/project/script.py >> /home/user/cron_log.txt 2>&1



This setup allows Chrome to run in non-headless mode by providing a virtual display environment.
